# Simple PHP/MYSQL Log in code only working for some people/clients

Tags: php, mysql, validation

**TL:DR:** This code, for some people it works, it executes, logs on and works fine, but for some people it only shows `0 results` (//commented at 2nd php code with Example1)

I'm having a very frustrating situation right now with my supposedly simple log in form where the problem is that my 'web-app' log in form works for some people, but for some it doesn't.

I've posted only the php code here which i have found to be not working as intended. Please do note that this code has undergone a lot of changes as a result of my endeavors to find a probable cause and fix to the issue from Google search results. Hence, I've commented the lines where i basically don't have a clue why i did that but i just did it because i read it somewhere that it might help.

These lines of code are included at the very beginning of the files on both files.

```
<?php session_start(); 
      ob_start();
?>
```

**Validation php:**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "****";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "*****";

// Get values
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];

//pass values
$_SESSION['login_value_user'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['login_value_password'] = $_POST['password'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pwd'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        if($user != 'lloki'){
            header('Location: http://bluebotdev.com/nav/workers.php');
            ob_get_clean(); // questionable google search solution
            exit();// questionable google search solution

         } else{

            header('Location: http://bluebotdev.com/php/lloki.php');
            ob_get_clean(); // questionable google search solution
            exit(); // questionable google search solution

         }    
    } 

} else {
     echo "   

      <div id='error'>

          <div class='container-fluid'>

              <div class='row'>

                  <div class='col-xs-10'>
       <a class='btn btn-danger extra-padding' href='../index.html'>Error! Wrong password or username!</a>
                   </div>

             </div>

       </div>

  </div> ";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

**After validation php code:**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

// Get values
$user = $_SESSION['login_value_user'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, surname,phone,address,email,workhours,status FROM workers WHERE name='$user' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table class='table'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Phone</th><th>Address</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row['surname']."</td><td>".$row['phone']."</td><td>".$row['address']."</td><td>".$row['email']."</td><td>".$row['status']."</td></tr>";
        $dummy_name = $row['name'];
        $dummy_surname = $row['surname'];
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
        echo "0 Results"; //Example 1
}
session_destroy(); // questionable google search solutions
$conn->close();

?>
```

So, just to be perfectly clear, this piece of code is up on my hosting server and tested on:

- multiple devices and different internet providers;
- in multiple countries such as Finland, Switzerland, and France
- across 10 testing devices/users: 5 of them can log in and view the site perfectly well as intended, 5 of them cannot, and receive the `0 results response`
- all of the testing users had a range of different devices, from S6 edge, S7 edge, iPhone 6, and iPhone 7
- all of them were given the same username and password to log on with.

I really am hoping for someone to enlighten me on whats going on here and hopefully guide me in the direction to fix this.

PS - I came here to Stackoverflow after 5 days of nonstop Google search solutions and causes to this, but I've honestly ran out of search terms to search for now.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the code looks fine, so you have to find *exactly why* it returns 0 results: maybe the `$user` variable was empty, it had an unexpected value, the DB call failed, etc.

In PHP a good option is create a log with all the relevant info (just a text file like the standard PHP log), you should include:

- Information about the user: at minimum user agent and IP.
- Information about the the operation: in your case the result of the operation (success/error), the value of `$user` (better a `var_dump()` of the `$_SESSION` array), and the result of the DB call (both `mysqli->info` and `mysqli->error`).

I would log also successful operations, because sometimes they could offer a clue about the fail pattern.

Once you have the first clue, add more information to the log: for example, if the problem is that the `$_SESSION['login_value_user']` is empty, log the session value in all the pages that use or change the session to find when the value is lost.

As a final note, you should make your log function as robust as possible, so you don't introduce extra errors or lost some entries if, for example, you try to log some variable that is not yet defined.

Comment: Also, proper use of PDO and not using variables directly in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your input, i will try to do the above mentioned, but also, just as a side note, it seems that there is a bug with the mariadb servers that my hosting company is using, and apparantly they are aware of it and trying to fix this, so the error that im having is not originating from the code but simply from a server bug as ive been told by the hosting company, thank you for your input guys.